# do-release-upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 - no development version

Tags: server, upgrade

I am currently using 18.04 LTS in the web server production environment. I was under the impression that Ubuntu 20.04 LTS was ready to go, since it was released in april 2020.

But running `do-release-upgrade` tells me "`There is no development version of an LTS available`".

Does this mean that 20.04 LTS is not ready yet?

Comment: LTS users usually want stability, so the upgrade doesn't occur until AFTER the first point release (which is likely in hours).  Even after 20.04.1 has been released (which is actually the date/time for the ISO release for new installs), it's a number of days before the *taps* get turned allowing the prior LTS release to detect and offer upgrade; which ensures stability.

Comment: This should not have been closed as a duplicate simply because some answers match, it is a bad message. Why would anyone upgrade to a development version anyway? By definition it is a risk?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Upgrade from 18.04 is done with 20.04.1 (note the .1).

That point release is set for release on august 6th 2020. So you need to wait a little bit longer as it is not the 6th all over the world yet.

It was initially set for July 23rd but that got postponed to Aug 6th.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense

Comment: I'm running 20.04, and it already updated to 20.04.1 more than a week ago. So I'm guessing august 6th is the day where it's possible to update from earlier versions to 20.04.1

Comment: Yes we 20.04 users got it on the 23rd of July :) Added that just before you made the comment :+)

Comment: That also explains why I couldn't find a reliable source on the date, since some said July 23 and others August 6 - turns out both were correct. ;-)

Comment: @ArturMeinild the date refers to the release of the ISO, which yes is after installed users get the upgrades.  As it stands right now, I see only one *product* that hasn't clicked *ready* for upgrade, but that'll happen... Upgrades from prior releases though occur **after** that date, a decision which is made & change to a file made when the deemed appropriate.  The date is ISO release only.

Comment: Well, as of today (7th August in the UK) My 18.04.4 system is still not seeing the 20.04.1 LTS upgrdae as being available. `do-release-upgrade` returns the message `There is no development version of an LTS available` so I'm upgrading with `do-release-upgrade -d` which says its upgrading to `20.04`.

Comment: After updating with `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` I can confirm I am now running 20.04.1 LTS.

Comment: @FatMonk what exactly do I get when I add the '-d' option? The "d" is for "development" right? Does this mean that I get a release not ready for production?

Comment: @Jette it seems not. It looks like the full release version 20.04.1. I had exactly the same concern as you because the docs describe `-d` as grabbing a dev release, but in this case as there 8s no Dev release available it grabbed the latest LTS version which I was not being offered by Software Updater.

Comment: @Jette no. Thing is ... at some point the development release equals the regular release. You can still use the -d but effectively it would be the same as downloading the current regular ISO and install that.

Comment: @Rinzwind I am currently upgrading 3 production webservers from 16.04 to 18.04. I am wondering if it is safe to proceed to 20.04 (while I'm at it)... or should I wait until I can do do-release-upgrade without the -d option?

Comment: Hmmm. If that is the case I (but I am not the-know-it-all ;) ) believe you are doing it wrong ;-) Going to a new LTS ... I would do that on a new system and not with an upgrade. 16.04 on system 1. 18.04 on system2. Works? Replace 16.04 with 20.04. Restore user data from 18.04 to 20.04.  If you only can do this on 1 system: go 16->18 then make sure it works and a couple of weeks later do 18->20. Never make upgrades more complex than needed :)

Comment: and now it is the 12th of august, and still "There is no development version of an LTS available." When precisely is it expected to become available?

Comment: Aug 13, on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. Without `-d`, I still get "There is no development version of an LTS available". Do you guys know where to find some more info on the general availability?

Comment: So it's 14th, more than a week later and still "There is no development version of an LTS available." both from do-release-upgrade and software updater. So I tempted to downvote this answer as completely incorrect unless some information w.r.t. delay is added (i.e. if there is some critical bug delaying the roll out or something else).

Comment: And now it's the 29th and it's still not yet ready. :\

Comment: Now we're well into September and it still won't do the update.

Answer (score 47):

According to the [Focal Fossa (20.04.1 LTS) Point-Release Status Tracking](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/focal-fossa-20-04-1-lts-point-release-status-tracking/17604) page, upgrades are not enabled yet due to "a few upgrade blockers".

This issue was reported as bug [#1890936](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1890936).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the tracker.  It makes the reason for delay clear.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed to know.

Comment: Thanks! It seems it's only this one left 
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1891680

Comment: @everyman Thanks for the info, let's hope they can fix it soon.